# How to pass an unicode char argument to ImageMagick?

Tags: python, unicode

Suppose the char of "▣" is in somefont.ttf's glyph table.

```
char = unichr(9635)

subprocess.call(['convert', '-font', 'somefont.ttf', '-size', '50x50', '-label:%s' % char, 'output.png'])

subprocess.call(['convert', '-font', 'somefont.ttf', '-size', '50x50', ('-label:%s' % char).encode('utf-8'), 'output.png'])
```

Both create an blank image with no char of "▣" on it. Is above code correct? Or the problem is on ImageMagick side which doesn't capture label in certain ranges?

The reason for using ImageMagick to draw text is it's more flexible than PIL to fix and align text to certain image size.

**EDIT:**

According to yuku's suggestion, I tried the following methods:

```
root@host:~@convert -font somefont.ttf -size 50x65 label:▣ output.png
root@host:~@convert -font somefont.ttf -size 50x65 label:'▣' output.png
```

Both outputs a question mark but not the correct character.

Comment: Maybe `'▣'` is not in the somefont.ttf?

Comment: @J.F. I just figured out that the char '▣' has blank data in somefont.ttf's glyph table.

Comment: this forum thread answers: https://legacy.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=18395

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try to get it working by hand using ASCII labels in your console.

```
    $ convert -font somefont.ttf -size 50x50 -label:A output.png
    convert: unrecognized option `-label:A' @ convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1753.
    1 ;( 
    $ convert -font somefont.ttf -size 50x50 -label A output.png
    convert: missing an image filename `output.png' @ convert.c/ConvertImageComm\
    and/2775.
    1 ;(
```

2. Use `subprocess.check_call` instead of `os.system`.

   ```
   import subprocess

   if __name__=="__main__":
       cmd = 'convert -font somefont.ttf -size 50x50'.split()
       #XXX command arguments are invalid 
       subprocess.check_call(cmd + ['-label', unichr(9635), 'output.png'])
   ```

Comment: '-label' and unichr(9635) should be in one element in cmd list otherwise you will get "convert: missing an image filename `output.png'" error.

Comment: @J.F. your first command should be right. why you got a "unrecognized option" error?

Comment: @jack: the first command is incorrect because there is `'-'` before `'label'`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this link](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#unicode), you need to pass the text encoded in UTF8.
It will be able to draw the correct character outside ASCII range.

Comment: char=unichr(9635) already encoded the character in unicode. what should I do?

Comment: also tried subprocess.call(['convert', '-font', 'somefont.ttf', '-size', '50x50', ('-label:%s' % char).encode('utf-8'), 'output.png']) but no success.

Comment: unicode is not the same as utf8, `unicode()` and `unichr()` return unicode objects while `unichr().encode('utf8')` creates a `str` object which is what you want. Also watch out for `LC_*` environment variables which also may play a role.

Comment: @Otto, yes, i tried encode('utf8') method. system locale are all en_US.UTF-8.

Comment: @yuku, I tried your method (convert -font somefont.ttf -size 50x65 label:▣ output.png). It outputs a question mark but not expected like what your link suggests.

Comment: Maybe your terminal encoding is not set correctly. Just a speculation.